# i want to draw a simple line from one image to other where drag and drop the image

Tags: android

I'm using drag and drop , I'm making matching concept , drag image from left to right, when answer will correct , at there i want to draw a line from left to right , i use many things as like

```
public class Dragtesting extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.drag);
        ViewGroup dlayout = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.dlayout);
  dlayout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View paramView, MotionEvent paramMotionEvent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(touchFlag==true){
 switch (paramMotionEvent.getActionMasked()) 
                {
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
 //getting the positions
break;
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
break;

  Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
  Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE);

canvas.drawLine(offset_x, offset_y, currentX, currentY, paint); 
  break;
                default:
                    break;
                }

          }
            return true;
        }
    });
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View paramView, MotionEvent paramMotionEvent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (paramMotionEvent.getActionMasked()) 
    {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        touchFlag=true;
        offset_x = (int) paramMotionEvent.getX();
        offset_y = (int) paramMotionEvent.getY();
       // tagvalue = (Integer) paramView.getTag();
        selected_item =  paramView;
        imageParams=paramView.getLayoutParams();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        selected_item=null;
        touchFlag=false;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }       
    return false;
}
```

this is not working , help me

Answer (score 1):

i have extends relative layout and make a design time view file, which is use to draw a line between image views , thanks to all to helps me, but that was not the right answer thats y m not accept other answer, m sory for that

Answer (score 0):

what do you get?

try writing 
`invalidate();`
before painting.

Comment: this message is shown;    The method invalidate() is undefined for the type new View.OnTouchListener(){}

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class LineView extends View {

    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    private float offset_x;
    private float offset_y;
    private float currentX;
    private float currentY;

    public LineView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            offset_x = currentX = event.getX();
            offset_y = currentY = event.getY();
        } else {
            currentX = event.getX();
            currentY = event.getY();
        }
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE);

        canvas.drawLine(offset_x, offset_y, currentX, currentY, paint);
    }
}
```

There you go. It should be like this. Tested :)

Comment: i am using this ___________public class Dragtesting extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{

Comment: And you shouldn't. Activity is kind of a container for windows and views. You have to add a content view and then Android will pass you the proper Canvas you can draw on. Using simple View is the recomended method unless it's JNI.

Comment: But, you're still using empty, uninitialized Canvas, which is not connected to any View nor Window. You should use the Canvas object passed to the draw() method of your R.id.dlayout. Also, using two methods of receiving input in one place may lead to problems. Try to keep your code clean and simple. For example you can move your touch events to one method inside R.id.dlayout as well.